# How can I know the output and input tensor names in a saved model

Tags: tensorflow

I know how to load a saved TensorFlow model but how will I know the input and output tensor names.

I can load a protobuf file using tf.import_graph_def and then load the tensors using function get_tensor_by_name but how will I know the tensor names of any pre-trained model. Do I need to check their documentation or is there any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input and output tensors are placeholders, something like this should be helpful for you:

```
X = np.ones((1,3), dtype=np.float32)
tf.reset_default_graph()
model_saver = tf.train.Saver(defer_build=True)
input_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,3], name="Input")
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3], stddev=0.01), name="Weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]), name="Bias")
output = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_pl, w), b)
model_saver.build()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
model_saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")
```

Now, that the graph is built and saved, we can see the placeholder names like this:

```
model_loader = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
model_loader.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
placeholders = [x for x in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if x.type == "Placeholder"]
# [<tf.Operation 'Input' type=Placeholder>]
```

Comment: Yes,in this way I can get the list of the tensors but how will I know the model architecture that is the input and output tensor.

Comment: That's why I gave a name to the input tensor when creating the graph. That way, when loading the graph you know which tensors to fetch so you can input data into the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the names and the input list for each operation in your graph to find the names of the tensors.

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(input_model_filepath, "rb") as f:
  graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
  tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

for op in graph.get_operations():
  print(op.name, [inp for inp in op.inputs])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution only for inputs:

```
# read pb into graph_def
with tf.gfile.GFile(input_model_filepath, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# import graph_def
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

# print operations
for op in graph.get_operations():
    if op.type == "Placeholder":
        print(op.name)
```