# Tensorflow: Can I run my tensorflow model directly in flask?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have created a tensorflow model, saved it and have tested it. I really don't know how to use tensorflow serving and I'm not sure about the input and output nodes of my model to convert it into protobuf and then use tensorflow serving. So, I wanted to know if I can directly use the prediction function on flask and load the model there to make the predictions? I am really confused as to why we have to use only tensorflow serving to deploy tensorflow models? Is there any easier direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can**, but you will need to set up a **TensorFlow Serving server**. Then you send a post request to the server.

**Reference link here**: [Deploying-keras-models-using-tensorflow-serving-and-flask](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-keras-models-using-tensorflow-serving-and-flask-508ba00f1037)

**Reference link here**: [Serving-TensorFlow flask client](https://github.com/aaxwaz/Serving-TensorFlow-Model/blob/master/flask_client.py)

```
"""This script wraps the client into a Flask server. It receives POST request with
prediction data, and forward the data to tensorflow server for inference.
"""

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, jsonify,Response
import json
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from grpc.beta import implementations
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server', 'localhost:9000', 'PredictionService host:port')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

app = Flask(__name__)


class mainSessRunning():
    def __init__(self):
        host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
        channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
        self.stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

        self.request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
        self.request.model_spec.name = 'example_model'
        self.request.model_spec.signature_name = 'prediction'

    def inference(self, val_x):
        # temp_data = numpy.random.randn(100, 3).astype(numpy.float32)
        temp_data = val_x.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 3)
        print("temp_data is:", temp_data)
        data, label = temp_data, np.sum(temp_data * np.array([1, 2, 3]).astype(np.float32), 1)
        self.request.inputs['input'].CopyFrom(
            tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data, shape=data.shape))

        result = self.stub.Predict(self.request, 5.0)
        return result, label


run = mainSessRunning()

print("Initialization done. ")


# Define a route for the default URL, which loads the form
@app.route('/inference', methods=['POST'])
def inference():
    request_data = request.json
    input_data = np.expand_dims(np.array(request_data), 0)
    result, label = run.inference(input_data)
    di={"result":str(result),'label': label[0].tolist()}
    return Response(json.dumps(di), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply but I wanted to know will this work for tensorflow models without keras as I have not used keras library and used tensorflow and ran the model usinf sess.run() so theres no model name persay.

Comment: Yes, it would work. I uploaded some code for your reference. Check out this link : https://github.com/aaxwaz/Serving-TensorFlow-Model/blob/master/flask_client.py

Comment: Is this model is .meta format or .pb format? Also, is there any way to find out the output and input tensors of a tensorflow model?

Comment: .meta format, I think both should work, but you need to write your only code for that. Read the graph and print by [n for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]. There is an answer on stackoverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313980/how-can-i-know-the-output-and-input-tensor-names-in-a-saved-model.

Comment: cant we simple load model  the saved model in flask app and do the prediction?

Comment: @alex3465 You can but then you need to load the model everytime you do a prediction again

Comment: I believe two major architectural problems tf serving solves is: batching requests so you can get additional throughput from gpu/tpu and preventing the need to duplicate the model in memory for each request. Something about the main tensorflow runtime/session stuff precludes multiple requests from leveraging the same model. This is a really big issue if you're gonna scale.